# If $f,g$ are Riemann-Integrable on $[a,b]$ then $h(x)=f(x)^{g(x)}$ is Riemann-Integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

If $f,g$ are Riemann-Integrable on $[a,b]$, and there is $m$ such that $0<m\leq{f(x)}$ for every $x$ in $[a,b]$ then $h(x)= f(x)^{g(x)}$ is Riemann-Integrable on $[a,b]$.
I want to use Lebesgue's Theorem, but I don't know how to prove that the set of
discontinuities of $h$ have measure zero.

Comment: Won't $h$ be continuous at any point where $f$ and $g$ both are?

Comment: @AnginaSeng, yes, but what implication does this have in the points of discontinuity?

Comment: you know that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $x$ then $h$ is. So, look at this in the contrapositive manner: if $h$ is not continuous at $x$ then either $f$ isn't continuous at $x$ or $g$ isn't continuous at $x$. i.e $D_h\subseteq D_f \cup D_g$, where $D_f$ represents the set of discontinuities of $f$. Since the two sets on the right have (Lebesgue) measure zero, so does their union, and hence the set on the left also has measure zero.

Comment: @peek-a-boo i got it. The problem was that i thought that perhaps $h$ could have discontinuities other than $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 1):

The function $h$ is bounded. And whenever $f$ and $g$ are continuous, $h$ is continuous too. So, since the sets of points of discontinuity of both $f$ and $g$ have Lebesgue measure $0$, the set of points of discontinuity of $h$ have Lebesgue measure $0$ too). See, you can indeed apply Lebesgue's theorem.

Comment: I don't see why the set of points of discontinuity of h is countable, that is because h depends of f and g? And f,g have countable points of discontinuity?

Comment: @MateoSotoArango I have edited my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: I think that's right, The problem was that i thought that perhaps $h$ could have discontinuities other than $f$ and $g$.  
Thanks for answering.

Comment: No, it cannot, since $h=f^g=\exp(g\log(f))$. So, $h$ can be obtained from $f$ and $g$ through composition.